# Notation regarding Subsets of Inner Product Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are two subsets of an inner product space $E$, then what exactly does 
$$(A+B)^\perp$$ mean. The question I am studying says to show that $(A+B)^\perp$ is equal to $(A \cup B)^\perp$. Does $(A+B)^\perp$ mean the addition of two vectors in $A$ and $B$?

Thanks a lot, I find this notation confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, an inner product space is a *vector* space equipped with an inner product.  So we have an addition operation.

So $A + B := \{ a + b \mid a \in A, b \in B \}$.  In other words, $A+ B$ is the set of all sums where the first element is from $A$ and the second element is from $B$.

If $A = \{1, 3\}$ and $B = \{2, 4\}$, then $A+ B = \{1 + 2, 1 + 4, 3 + 2, 3 + 4\}$.

Comment: To address your question, $C^{\perp}$ is the set of vectors in the entire space that are perpendicular to every vector in $C$.  So $(A + B)^{\perp}$ is the set of vectors perpendicular to every vector of the form $a + b$.